# Repeat Android services with differents times

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, repeat

I created a broadcast receiver which starts three services.
Those services don't have the same Intent, they don't have the same repeatTime and they don't have the same ID

Here's how I create it

The calling method is :

```
        createAndStartService(context, intentMobile, REPEAT_TIME_MOBILE, 12);
        createAndStartService(context, intentNetwork, REPEAT_TIME_NETWORK, 13);
        createAndStartService(context, intentSystem, REPEAT_TIME_SYSTEM, 14);
```

and the method starting the services contains this :

```
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), repeatTime, pending);
```

**I can't figure out why the repeatTime is always overridden by the last value specified.**

The code works well once, and then my three services are synchronized.
If you have any idea to help me figuring out what's the problem there, thank you !

**EDIT:**

Hendra Wijaya Djiono pointed out that since Kitkat, Android OS synchronizes the services to avoid a waste of ressources. I tried a lot of different workarounds but nothing really worked.

The only solution I found was to set a repeat time much larger between my services : if I ask a service to repeat every 5mins and the other one every 15mins, no problems !

Comment: Maybe it is better if you can include your method name and parameters itself of createAndStartService so we know the parameters

Comment: My current guess is because you use setInexactRepeating. Because 3 of them can be run at the same time for eficiency

Comment: Hey ! No luck so far, even with a setRepeating.

I'm trying to implement a JobScheduler instead of an AlarmManager but the results are exactly the same : the jobs synchronized and the three services are executed at the same time.

Comment: If you are using android version >= Kitkat, then the behaviour will be like that. Check documentation on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html on the note section. To get a workaround, you can use setExact and repeat the setExact on the PendingIntent that you set.

Comment: A BIG thank you for pointing that out ! 

FYI, I tried the workaround suggested (setExact repeated in the PendingIntent) but the result is exactly the same. 
The real problem is that I tried to repeat my services every 2, 3 and 4 minutes. This timelapse is way too short and Android decides to synchronize them and doesn't care about my repeat time.
Setting repeat times of 5 / 10 / 15mins works well.

Thanks again !